# Redirect "/" to "/web" using IIS7

Tags: iis, redirection, iis-7

I'm hosting a site where I would like for various reasons to have `http://mydomain.com` automatically redirect to `http://mydomain.com/web` while at the same time still allowing `http://mydomain.com/foo.html` to be served.

Using HTTP Redirect from IIS 7 I seem to be creating an endless redirect loop. Would you have any hints for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you only want request for / to be redirected. In the case, check for an empty URL and then redirect to /web/ as shown in this web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to /web" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/web/" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you have moved your entire site under /web/ and want to redirect every old URL to it's new URL under /web/ except those that have a matching file or directory, you simply check all URL's that don't start with web/ and don't match a file and directory and redirect those:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to /web" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^web/" negate="true" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/web{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can we do the same thing fro rewrite? I want / to be rewritten to /web/